# react router v6 ошибка при обновлении страницы с параметром в адресной строке

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-router-dom

Когда я пытаюсь перейти по адресу `http://127.0.0.1:3000/order/1` через ссылку роутера или через `navigate()`, то все работает хорошо, но когда я обновляю страницу или напрямую меня строку браузера, чтобы перейти на страницу с параметром, то я всегда получаю ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это происходит, только на страницу с параметрами `localhost/page/:param`

Мой компонент с основной логикой:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from "./shared/Layout";
import { publicRoutes } from "./routes";
import http from "./api/http";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "!style-loader!css-loader!react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
export default function Application() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [CurrentComponent, setCurrentComponent] = React.useState<React.ReactNode | null>(null);
  const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = React.useState(location.pathname);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("cart_id") && !localStorage.getItem("token")) {
      const fetchAccount = async () => {
        await http
          .post("/api/v1/cart/create_cart")
          .then((response) => {
            localStorage.setItem("cart_id", response?.data?.id);
          })
          .catch((error) => console.error(error));
      };
      fetchAccount();
    }
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const getRoute = async () => {
      // получаем имя нужного компонента любым способом
      let url: null | string = null;

      for (let i = 0; i < publicRoutes.length; i++) {
        if (location.pathname.includes(publicRoutes[i]?.simplePath || publicRoutes[i]?.path)) {
          setCurrentUrl(publicRoutes[i]?.path)

          url = publicRoutes[i]?.prjPath;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (url === null) {
        url = "NotFoundPage";
      }
      // загружаем компонент по его названию
      const CurrentComponent = React.lazy(() => import("./routes/" + url));

      // записываем компонент в состояние
      setCurrentComponent(CurrentComponent);
    };

    getRoute();
  }, [location]);
  

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timeStamp = Number(localStorage.getItem("timeStamp"));
    if (Date.now() - timeStamp >= 86400000) {
      localStorage.removeItem("timeStamp");
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
    }
  }, []);

  // const getPublicRoutes = useCallback(
  //   () =>
  //     publicRoutes.map((route) => (
  //       <Route key={route.path} path={route.path} element={route.element} />
  //     )),
  //   // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  //   [publicRoutes]
  // );

  return (
    <React.Suspense>
      <Layout>
        <ToastContainer hideProgressBar={true} theme="colored" />{" "}
        {/* уведомления */}
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path={currentUrl}
            element={CurrentComponent ? <CurrentComponent /> : null}
          />
        </Routes>
      </Layout>
    </React.Suspense>
  );
}
```

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/index.tsx'),
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/index.html'),
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-typescript', '@babel/preset-env'],
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(?:ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|svg|webp)$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|)$/,
                type: 'asset/inline',
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит потому, что при прямом переходе по адресу роутер ещё не заполнен, он начинает заполняться уже после вызова страницы, соответственно ничего не загружается. Если же переход идёт через `navigate`, то соответственно все пути уже в роутере, и нужная страница грузится.

Через `map` всех путей подобную задачу не решить. Примерный порядок действий - перехватить `url`, получить необходимый для загрузки компонент для полученного `url`, и, соответственно, загрузить его.

Для начала, чтобы роутер не выкидывал ошибок, он должен увидеть `Route` с атрибутом `path` соответствующим текущему `url`:

```
const location = useLocation();
const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = useState(location.pathname);
...
<Route path={currentUrl} />
```

Далее, нам нужно получить компонент, который должен быть загружен. Для этого понадобится какой-нибудь контроллер на сервере, который в обмен на полученный `url` выдаст в ответ имя нужного компонента, либо сделать кэш-файл, из которого можно будет получить имя нужного компонента прямо на клиентской части. Так или иначе, нужен компонент, например `CurrentComponent`:

```
    const [CurrentComponent, setCurrentComponent] = useState();
...
    <Route
        path={currentUrl}
        element={CurrentComponent ? <CurrentComponent /> : null}
    />
```

И, наконец, нужно определить и загрузить этот самый компонент через `lazy` при смене url:

```
 const location = useLocation();
 useEffect(() => {

    const getRoute = async () => {
        // получаем имя нужного компонента любым способом
        const response = ...;
            
        // загружаем компонент по его названию
        const CurrentComponent = lazy(() =>
            import("./" + response)
        );
            
        // записываем компонент в состояние
        setCurrentComponent(CurrentComponent);
    };
    
    getRoute();
}, [location]);
```

И, так как используем `lazy`, оборачиваем роутер в `Suspense`:

```
<Suspense>
    <Routes>
        <Route
            path={currentUrl}
            element={CurrentComponent ? <CurrentComponent /> : null}
        />
    </Routes>
</Suspense>
```

Итоговый результат:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Routes,
    Route,
    useLocation
} from 'react-router-dom';
...
const location = useLocation();

const [CurrentComponent, setCurrentComponent] = useState();
const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = useState(location.pathname);

useEffect(() => {
    
    const getRoute = async () => {
        // получаем имя нужного компонента любым способом
        const response = ...;
                
        // загружаем компонент по его названию
        const CurrentComponent = lazy(() =>
            import("./" + response)
        );
                
        // записываем компонент в состояние
        setCurrentComponent(CurrentComponent);
    };
        
    getRoute();
}, [location]);

<Suspense>
    <Routes>
        <Route
            path={currentUrl}
            element={CurrentComponent ? <CurrentComponent /> : null}
        />
    </Routes>
</Suspense>
```

Comment: Обновил описание, сделал также, как показано у тебя, но результат такой же как и был при обновлении страницы на роуте с параметром приходит такая же ошибка

Comment: Я когда ставил debugger, то у меня даже до useEffect не доходило, а уже ошибка прилетала